# How long is the EASA ATPL theory exam valid?

Tags: easa-regulations, pilot-certification, cpl

I got the JAA CPL and IR and ATPL theory examination in Spain in 2009. They are all expired by now. I didn't renew them until now because I'm flying with the CAAC license and got 3600 hours experience time. 
I want to endorse A320 type rating on the EASA license in order to fly in other countrys. They recruiment requirements are EASA CPL(or ATPL) with IR and MEP and (frozen ATPL).

My questions are:

- Is the ATPL theory examination expired or is it called the frozen ATPL?
- If I hold the valid IR issued by an ICAO member state China,  is the Cross-crediting applicable to RENEWAL of the EASA IR and MEP?

Comment: This question is better to be asked to the CAA were you want your EASA A320 rating to be endorsed by. They will be the ones that can clarify this to you.
I remember that in 2007 my JAA frozen ATPL had a valid theory for around 7 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FCL.025 is very clear on that and it says:

> (2) The completion of the airline transport pilot licence (ATPL) theoretical knowledge examinations will remain valid for the issue of an ATPL for a period of 7 years from the last validity date of:
>   (i) an IR entered in the licence; or
>   (ii) in the case of helicopters, a helicopter’s type rating entered in that licence.

ATPL theory exams are valid for 7 years of the date of expiry of IR, entered in EASA licence. So it depends when your EASA IR expired. ICAO IR unfortunately does not count in this case.

If your ATPL theory exams are not valid anymore, you will have to do them again. It is possible to transfer A320 rating from CAAC (ICAO) licence to an EASA one - depending on your experience. You would need, however, to do LST (licence skill test) on A320 in the simulator and pass all 14 EASA ATPL exams again.